# Analitycs - How to improve the limit to "over 100 sites"

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I need to put more than 100 sites in my [analytics project](https://www.google.com/analytics/) But the only response that I find is "Not possible!"

- Is that so?
- Only 100 site per account?
- How to improve this? **(maybe to 1.200 sites...)**

Thanks!

Comment: You can have 100 accounts per e-mail address with 50 unique properties each, so that's 500 websites (assuming one domain per tracking id). Easiest way to get more is to get another e-mail address. However it'S unclear what you mean by "Google Analytics Project" plus I'm not sure this is on topic (seems general reference to me).

Comment: @EikePierstorff That would be 5,000 not 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can CREATE 100 accounts per login, but you can HAVE a lot more.

Use one login (A) to create new accounts, and use a different login (B) exclusively for reporting -- create with (A), grant access to (B), optionally remove (A) or use logins C, D, E, F to create more accounts.

I know some agencies create a Gmail account 'AgencynameClientname@gmail.com' and use that to create a new account, then grant admin access to their agency account(s) for reporting and day-to-day management. Should a client leave their service, they remove their access and give the original Gmail account to the client.

Comment: This has changed since the original answer was written.  It now seems like you cannot have more than 100, no matter how they are added. You need to make a request to Google to allow for more...or so I've heard from others.